# Extracting linked files from a Windows executable using Python

Tags: python, windows, linker

I'm unfamiliar with the terminology used for linking files into executables as they are compiled.

I want to write a Python script that extracts .icos from Windows executables that are viewable when you make file associations inside Folder Options. These are simply *linked* into the executable file upon compilation.

Then the script would sort the .ico files into individual folders based on their origin (it's supposed to extract all from subfolders/recursively) and even tell the difference between recently installed files and files that were left there previously.

Is there a library available that does such? Would I have to use a Python "Windows unlinker" or could I have it scan through RC resources too? Would there at least be a .DLL I can access with Python that does so?

Comment: Apparently I can use 7-Zip to open up the contents of .exe files if I fiddle with the commandline options a bit. .exe support like an archive is not even listed on its webpage! Any other options?

Comment: If you want filesystem operations you do it with filesystem operations. 7-Zip it is.